# Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server in next js how to fix that?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

this line of code produce Error:

```
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

What's wrong here and how to fix that issue.

```
const initialState = {
    cart: {
        cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful => https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35773

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera could you explain exactly why this occurs and how to fix that. I tried many solutions from github but can't find a way to fix this.

Comment: My best guess is your page is rendered in server some skeleton dom string and after it is received to the browser, in the browser react client generates the virtual dom and tries to match both doms and finds a mismatch.  Once I sort out kind of a issue by keeping a proper unique css class names in the divs.

Comment: Let's say a whole div is missing in server-rendered dom and if the react hydration algorithm fails to identify it properly then this error pops up.